# error: field has incomplete type

Tags: c++, classes, arduino

Eu recebo este erro

> error: field has incomplete type

ao fazer algo como:

```
class MinhaClasse
{
   MinhaClasse teste; // Erro aqui
};
```

Eu já tentei adicionar essa linha no começo do código `class MinhaClasse;`, mas não funcionou.

Eu entendo o erro, mas não sei como posso resolver.

Comment: o que você deseja realmente fazer?

Comment: @rLinhares O código acima é apenas um exemplo do erro, o código completo é muito grande, por isso não incluí na pergunta

Comment: Eu nem sabia que `C` tinha classes. Não seria C++ ?

Comment: Qual é a finalidade de `MinhaClasse`?

Comment: @lazyFox Isto é só um exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro já diz o problema. Para definir `MinhaClasse` precisa definir `MinhaClasse`, e entre em *loop* infinito, não tem solução.

Na verdade tem uma solução, é transformar o campo em um ponteiro, aí ele sabe exatamente de como se compõe o campo já que ele é um ponteiro, algo que o compilador já conhece. Ou seja, uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) resolve o problema. Pode não ser o que deseja, mas é a única forma.

```
class MinhaClasse { MinhaClasse *teste; };
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pKtGnM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bsmeumde-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/IncompleteType.cpp).

ou

```
class MinhaClasse { MinhaClasse unique_ptr<teste>; };
```